# python - opening an GUI from a list

Tags: python, class, tkinter

```
    import random
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk

    scores = []
    score = 0

    #introduction
    def start():
        print("             Welcome to Maths Smash                   \n")
        print("Complete the questions the quickest to get a high score\n")
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        print("Ok", name, "let's begin!")

    #menu
    def main():

        choice = None
        while choice !="0":
            print(
            """
            Maths Smash

            0 - Exit
            1 - Easy
            2 - Medium
            3 - Hard
            4 - Extreme
            5 - Dashboard
            """
            )

            choice = input("Choice: ")
            print()

        #exit
            if choice == "0":
                print("Good-bye!")
                break
        #easy
            elif choice == "1":
                print("                       Easy Level                            ")
                print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")            
                easy_level()
        #medium
            elif choice == "2":
                print("                       Medium Level                          ")
                print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")
                medium_level()
        #hard
            elif choice == "3":
                print("                       Hard Level                            ")
                print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")
                hard_level()
        #extreme
            elif choice == "4":
                print("                     Extreme Level                           ")
                print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")
                extreme_level()
        #teacher login
            elif choice == "5":
                print("Dashboard")
                dashboard(Frame)
        #if the input does not = to choices        
        else:
            print("Sorry but", choice, "isn't a vaild choice.")

    class dashboard(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            super(dashboard, self).__init__(master)
            self.grid()
            self.main_menu()

        def main_menu(self):        
            #student dashboard button
            bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Student",
                           command=self.student, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn1.grid()

            #teacher dashboard button
            bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Teacher",
                           command=self.teacher, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn2.grid()

            #exit button
            bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Exit",
                   command=root.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn3.grid()

            self.main_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3  # Save button widgets.

        def student(self):
            for button in self.main_page_buttons:  # Hide the main page Buttons.
                button.grid_forget()

            #view highscores button
            bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Highscores",
                           command=self.view_scores, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn1.grid()

            #print score button
            bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Save Score",
                           command=self.save_score, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn2.grid()

            #exit button
            bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Exit",
                   command=root.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn3.grid()

            self.student_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3  # Save button widgets.

        def save_score(self):
            f = open("Maths Test Score.txt','w")
            score = input("What did you score?\n")
            f.write(name, score)
            f.close()


        def teacher(self):
            for button in self.main_page_buttons:  # Hide the main page Buttons.
                button.grid_forget()
            #add highscores button
            bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Add Highscore",
                           command=self.add_score, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn1.grid()

            #remove score button
            bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Remove Highscore",
                           command=self.remove_score, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn2.grid()

            #view highscores
            bttn3 = Button(self, text = "View Highscores",
                           command=self.view_scores, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn3.grid()

            #exit button
            bttn4 = Button(self, text = "Exit",
                           command=root.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
            bttn4.grid()

            self.teacher_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3, bttn4  # Save button widgets.

        def add_score(self):
            global scores
            score = int(input("What score do you want to add?\n"))
            scores.append(score)

        def remove_score(self):
            global scores
            score = int(input("Remove which score?\n"))
            if score in scores:
                scores.remove(score)

        def view_scores(self):
            global scores
            print("High Scores")
            for score in scores:
                print(score)     

    #calling functions
    start()
    main()

    #main for gui
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Dashboard")
    root.geometry("300x170")
    app = dashboard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Being trying to get this to work for a while now but, what I want to do is open the GUI when the user enters choice '5' but I'm not sure if there is a different way to call a class or something, have looked online for a bit couldn't see any useful examples to help. Any help would be much appreciated, cheers.

Comment: do you get error message ? Always add full error message (Traceback) in question.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'

Comment: add **full** error message (Traceback) **in question**. There are other useful informantion - for example there is line of code which makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't run code at this moment but I see one mistake.

When `dashboard` is created it needs parent instance - like `root` - but in `menu()` you use `Frame` which is class name, not instance.

In `menu()` you will have to create `root` before you create `dashboard`, and use `root.mainloop()` after that.

```
elif choice == "5":
    print("Dashboard")
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Dashboard")
    root.geometry("300x170")
    app = dashboard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** full working code.

Because now `root` is local variable inside `main()` so in `dashboard` I use `self.master` instead of `root` - see `command=self.master.destroy`

```
import random
from tkinter import *

scores = []
score = 0

#introduction
def start():
    print("             Welcome to Maths Smash                   \n")
    print("Complete the questions the quickest to get a high score\n")
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("Ok", name, "let's begin!")

#menu
def main():

    choice = None
    while choice !="0":
        print(
        """
        Maths Smash

        0 - Exit
        1 - Easy
        2 - Medium
        3 - Hard
        4 - Extreme
        5 - Dashboard
        """
        )

        choice = input("Choice: ")
        print()

    #exit
        if choice == "0":
            print("Good-bye!")
            break
    #easy
        elif choice == "1":
            print("                       Easy Level                            ")
            print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")            
            easy_level()
    #medium
        elif choice == "2":
            print("                       Medium Level                          ")
            print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")
            medium_level()
    #hard
        elif choice == "3":
            print("                       Hard Level                            ")
            print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")
            hard_level()
    #extreme
        elif choice == "4":
            print("                     Extreme Level                           ")
            print("Complete the test within two minutes to get 10 extra points\n")
            extreme_level()
    #teacher login
        elif choice == "5":
            print("Dashboard")

            root = Tk()
            root.title("Dashboard")
            root.geometry("300x170")
            app = Dashboard(root)
            root.mainloop()

        #if the input does not = to choices        
    else:
        print("Sorry but", choice, "isn't a vaild choice.")

class Dashboard(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Dashboard, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.main_menu()

    def main_menu(self):        
        #student dashboard button
        bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Student",
                       command=self.student, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn1.grid()

        #teacher dashboard button
        bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Teacher",
                       command=self.teacher, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn2.grid()

        #exit button
        bttn3 = Button(self, text="Exit",
               command=self.master.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn3.grid()

        self.main_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3  # Save button widgets.

    def student(self):
        for button in self.main_page_buttons:  # Hide the main page Buttons.
            button.grid_forget()

        #view highscores button
        bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Highscores",
                       command=self.view_scores, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn1.grid()

        #print score button
        bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Save Score",
                       command=self.save_score, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn2.grid()

        #exit button
        bttn3 = Button(self, text = "Exit",
               command=self.master.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn3.grid()

        self.student_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3  # Save button widgets.

    def save_score(self):
        f = open("Maths Test Score.txt','w")
        score = input("What did you score?\n")
        f.write(name, score)
        f.close()


    def teacher(self):
        for button in self.main_page_buttons:  # Hide the main page Buttons.
            button.grid_forget()

        #add highscores button
        bttn1 = Button(self, text = "Add Highscore",
                       command=self.add_score, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn1.grid()

        #remove score button
        bttn2 = Button(self, text = "Remove Highscore",
                       command=self.remove_score, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn2.grid()

        #view highscores
        bttn3 = Button(self, text = "View Highscores",
                       command=self.view_scores, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn3.grid()

        #exit button
        bttn4 = Button(self, text = "Exit",
                       command=self.master.destroy, height = 2, width= 15)
        bttn4.grid()

        self.teacher_page_buttons = bttn1, bttn2, bttn3, bttn4  # Save button widgets.

    def add_score(self):
        global scores

        score = int(input("What score do you want to add?\n"))
        scores.append(score)

    def remove_score(self):
        global scores

        score = int(input("Remove which score?\n"))
        if score in scores:
            scores.remove(score)

    def view_scores(self):
        global scores

        print("High Scores")
        for score in scores:
            print(score)     

#calling functions
start()
main()
```